# Can any integer be written as the sum of $M$ odd powers?

Tags: number-theory

Let $p \geq 1$ be odd. Is there always an $M \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ there exist (not necessarily distinct) integers $a_1, a_2 \cdots a_{M}$ such that $n = \sum_{i=1}^{M} a_i^p$? In other words, if we fix an odd number $p$, is there a number $M$ such that any integer $n$ can be written as the sum of $M$ $p$-powers.

This question is motivated by (and a strengthening of) [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207366/can-any-integer-can-be-written-as-the-sum-of-8-integer-cubes) fact, namely that any integer can be written as the sum of $8$ cubes.

Comment: Yes by the Hilbert-Waring theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Waring's problem
and the answer is yes.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem