# For any integer n, $78n^2+72n+2018$ is expressed as sum of four perfect cubes.

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares, perfect-powers

For any integer n, $$78n^2+72n+2018$$ is expressed as sum of four perfect cubes.

Is this possible that any integer can fit into this expression with 4 perfect cubes?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2723906/122489

Comment: That's your third question in the past few hours involving $2018$. Just curious, where do these come from?

Comment: This is not concerning your question but maybe it is helpful. Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ be an arbitrary integer, then $6k$ is expressed as the sum of four perfect cubes. 
$$6k = \Big( k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 \Big) \\ 
+ \Big( k^3 - 3k^2 + 3k - 1 \Big) + \Big(-k\Big)^3 + \Big(-k\Big)^3 \\ 
=(k+1)^3+(k-1)^3+(-k)^3+(-k)^3.$$

Answer (score 6):

Try this expression:
$$78n^2+72n+2018 = (n+a)^3+(n+b)^3+(-n+c)^3+(-n+d)^3.$$
Then
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
78n^2=3n^2(a+b+c+d);\\
72n = 3n(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2);\\
2018 = a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3.\end{array}\right.
$$
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
a+b+c+d=26;\\a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2=24;\\
a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=2018.\end{array}\right.
$$

This system has integer solution $a=1, b=11, c=7, d=7$.

Therefore 
$$
78n^2+72n+2018=(1+n)^3+(11+n)^3+(7-n)^3+(7-n)^3.
$$

---

Many numbers of the form $$78n^2+72n+2018$$ can be expressed as sum of up to four **positive** cubes too, but not all ($n=16$: $23138$, $n=22$: $41354$, $\ldots$).

Few examples:
$7$: $6344=2^3+ 8^3+ 12^3+ 16^3\quad (=8^3+18^3)$;
$8$: $7586=6^3+ 9^3+ 12^3+ 17^3$;
$9$: $8984=5^3+ 10^3+ 10^3+ 19^3$;
$10$: $10538=5^3+ 6^3+ 13^3+ 20^3\quad (=11^3+15^3+18^3)$;
$11$: $12248=3^3+ 3^3+ 3^3+ 23^3$;
$12$: $14114=3^3+ 4^3+ 15^3+ 22^3$;
$13$: $16136=2^3+ 2^3+ 19^3+ 21^3\quad (=14^3+14^3+22^3)$ ;
$14$: $18314=1^3+ 2^3+ 9^3+ 26^3$;
$15$: $20648=10^3+ 10^3+ 20^3+ 22^3$;

$17$: $25784\;(=4^3+ 11^3+ 29^3)$;
$19$: $31544=8^3+ 8^3+ 9^3+ 31^3$;
$20$: $34658=1^3+ 14^3+ 17^3+ 30^3$;
$21$: $37928=2^3+ 7^3+ 25^3+ 28^3$.

Comment: Nicely done....